# Error creating bean with name 'korisnikController' defined in file

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

Right now I am working on some college project with Spring Boot and MySQL db, and I got this error in console for Service, Controller and Repository class of "Korisnik". Can't find solution on internet for now and still losing plenty of time on that.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'korisnikService' defined in file [/home/sombor/Downloads/Book Your Flight/Book-Your-Flight/target/classes/com/bookyourflight/Book/Your/Flight/korisnik/KorisnikService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'korisnikRepository' defined in com.bookyourflight.Book.Your.Flight.korisnik.KorisnikRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.bookyourflight.Book.Your.Flight.korisnik.Korisnik

Tried to find solution on internet, expected to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `@Entity` annotation plus getters and setters.

```
@Entity
public class Korisnik {
 /*
   Getters and Setters...
 */
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have it together with @Table annotation.